# SSIS Execute SQL Task passing an array of parameters to a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have an SSIS Package that is a generic data exporter. I have a jobs table in a database that the package will run. Currently this works by reading SQL stored in a column and then executing it.

I am in the process of converting the sql stored into the column to a stored procedure (as it can be checked in to source control).The problem I have is that different jobs have different numbers of parameters for the SQL.

So, I have a table containing job id, parameter name, parameter value and parameter order.

How do I, in an Execute SQL Task, assign the parameters to the stored procedure? As I don't know how many parameters there are.

I suppose I could build a string of

```
exec proc param1value, param2value
```

in a script task and set a variable to that, I was just wondering if there was a way of passing a variable containing an array of parameters to the task?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't pass an array of parameters to an ExecuteSQL task.

You can execute a Dynamic SQL String as you described, but what I would do is only pass a single parameter (JobId, or whatever the PK of the Jobs table is) to the stored procedure, and have the stored procedure handle the logic of the other parameters.

> So, I have a table containing job id, parameter name, parameter value
>   and parameter order.

So all the stored procedure would need to do is query that table and get all the rows for the job id, and build a dynamic sql string using all the parameter name/value pairs and execute it.